# Save pandas dataframe with numpy arrays column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let us consider the following pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,np.array([6,7])],[4,np.array([8,9])]], columns = {'A','B'})
```

[image]

where the **B** column is composed by two numpy arrays.

If we save the dataframe and the load it again, the numpy array is converted into a string.

```
df.to_csv('test.csv', index = False)
df.read_csv('test.csv')
```

Is there any simple way of solve this problem? Here is the output of the loaded dataframe.

[image]

Comment: What about np.savez('filename',labels)  or savetext or other similar options? It stores arrays

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you can pickle the data instead.

```
df.to_pickle('test.csv')
df = pd.read_pickle('test.csv')
```

This will ensure that the format remains the same. However, it is not human readable

If human readability is an issue, I would recommend converting it to a json file

```
df.to_json('abc.json')
df = pd.read_json('abc.json')
```

Comment: Just be careful. Pickling for your own use is fine. But it can be incompatible across pandas versions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function to format each row.

```
def formatting(string_numpy):
"""formatting : Conversion of String List to List

Args:
    string_numpy (str)
Returns:
    l (list): list of values
"""
list_values = string_numpy.split(", ")
list_values[0] = list_values[0][2:]
list_values[-1] = list_values[-1][:-2]
return list_values
```

Then use the following apply function to convert it back into numpy arrays.

```
df[col] = df.col.apply(formatting)
```